# How to Dynamically create ETL jobs in AWS Glue with workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I am trying to perform dynamic /programmatic ETL jobs in glue with basic mapping and Transformations.

Scenarios are below,

1. new files comes in particular S3 bucket, job should trigger and to load in another s3 location.
2. how to handle dynamic mapping and transformation (Using config file).
3. how to create dynamic / programmatic Glue workflow to handle point 1 and 2.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.